# table with records that can be arranged

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

How can I make a table that has rows with order to one another and can be rearranged:
Example:

```
Rows:idappearance name
Records
 (1,"john"),(2,"mike")
```

Now, I want to insert "Avi" between them:
not having to worry about rearranging them

```
(1,"john"),(2,"Avi"),(3,"mike")
```

- This table can have a foreign key in
  another table (like departments..).
- idappearance is the order of appearance I want
  to set, doesn't need to be PK.
- It needs to handle about 50K of names so O(n) isn't best solution.

Comment: Why would Avi be inserted between john and mike?

Comment: @Lieven Because it's axiomatic in the question that that is the order he desires.

Comment: @RB: what I was trying to get at was "how do you determine the sort order of record X". If we now that, we might be able to come up with alternatives. Worst case and not advisable, you could be updating each and every row for every name added.

Comment: @Lieven The sort order is determined by the appearanceOrder, which is supplied by the database client.

Comment: @RB: I know but we had a similar request once about ordering isotopes. In the end, all that needed was to sort on atomic number (wich is fixed for each isotope) so there was no need to try to juggle around with id's. OP has not yet clarified this. *<Quote>If what you want is to do Y, you should ask that question without pre-supposing the use of a method that may not be appropriate. Questions of this form often indicate a person who is not merely ignorant about X, but confused about what problem Y they are solving and too fixated on the details of their particular situation</Quote>*

Comment: @Lieven I see your point. I've come across a similar requirement before, so it didn't occur to me that it was questionable. On reflection, I agree that it would be worth understanding the problem better!

Comment: let's say john,avi and mike are names for tests to be run in particular order, that can be updated tomorrow

Comment: In that case I believe you would be better of by treating your data as a linked list with a pointer to the next (and previous if needed) value. It would seriously speed up your updates at the expense of adding one (or two) columns.

Comment: Your initial state could be `(1, john, 2), (2, mike, null)`. Inserting Avi would then require one insert and one update. Your data then becomes `(1, john, 3), (3, Avi, 2), (2, mike, null)`

Comment: @Lieven I'm referring to the way it will be stored into a database. when the process runs it is different.

Comment: @shevski: so am I?! Rename `idappearance` to `id` and add a column to your table that points to the next record.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution would be having reasonable numerical gaps between records. In other words;

(10000,"John"),(20000,"mike")

(10000,"John"),(15000,"Avi"),(20000,"mike")

(10000,"John"),(12500,"tom"),(15000,"avi"),(20000,"mike")

etc..

Gap between records should be determined based on your data domain

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Another option is to use a non-integer type like `DECIMAL`. `NUMERIC` in postgres is ideal - I'm not sure if there is anything better then `DECIMAL` in MySQL. Should probably also have uniqueness enforced?

Comment: The problem with that is that an insert becomes a form of binary-chop. Leaving a gap of 10000 between 2 rows might leave you able to insert only 14 items (2^14 = 16384). Note I am assuming that you will always insert an element half-way between 2 elements but that is the likely algorithm.

Comment: liked it even tho it's finite

Comment: @shevski This approach will scale **very** poorly. It is very likely that it would not scale to 100K records, for the reason I've already given.

Comment: @RB I'm not claiming that this solution scale good. It depends upon your data. This solution is simple and just for the tables (e.g. lookup tables) that will house finite number of records.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a trigger on inserts. I don't use MySQL, but here's the code for sql-server...

Basically, on an insert, the trigger increments the appearanceId of all rows with appearanceId which are equal to or greater than the new appearance id.

```
CREATE Table OrderedTable
(
    id  int IDENTITY,
    name varchar(50),
    appearanceOrder int
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
   ON  dbo.OrderedTable
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE OrderedTable SET
        AppearanceOrder = AppearanceOrder + 1
    WHERE   AppearanceOrder >= (
        SELECT TOP 1 AppearanceOrder 
        FROM inserted )
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM inserted )

END
GO

INSERT INTO OrderedTable VALUES ('Alice', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderedTable VALUES ('Bob', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderedTable VALUES ('Charlie', 1)
INSERT INTO OrderedTable VALUES ('David', 1)
```

This returns David, Charlie, Bob, Alice as expected.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OrderedTable
ORDER BY    AppearanceOrder
```

Note that I haven't fully tested this implementation. One issue is that it will leave holes in the AppearanceOrder if items are deleted, or the inserts deliberately insert outside the current range. If these matter, they are left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: @shevski Are you asking if this approach will scale to 100K tests? Yes, it will scale fine.

Comment: I see, it's pretty nice, I thought there something that is "off the shelf" for this.

Comment: @Shevski - the "off the shelf" solution is to structure your data properly for your application...

Answer (score 0):

If *appearance order* were a double-precision floating point number, you could insert any name between any two adjacent names with a single insert. If you start with a table like this:

```
create table test (
    person_id integer primary key,
    person_name varchar(10) not null,
    appearance_order double precision not null unique
);

insert into test values (100, 'John', 11);
insert into test values (23, 'Mike', 12);
```

Insert Avi between them by simply

```
insert into test values (3, 'Avi', 11.5);
```

Sort by the column 'appearance_order'.

```
select * from test order by appearance_order
100   John   11
3     Avi    11.5
23    Mike   12
```

Insert Eva between John and Avi by

```
insert into test values (31, 'Eva', 11.25);

select * from test order by appearance_order
100   John   11
31    Eva    11.25
3     Avi    11.5
23    Mike   12
```

You *do* need to separate identification from sort order. That means using one column for the id number (and as the target for foreign key references) and another for the appearance order. But, depending on your application, you might not need a unique constraint on appearance_order.